# cakephp: add and edit in single view

Tags: php, templates, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i am working in cakephp n am new to it. I have created a view to add data into database. I wish to edit the record- when user clicks on edit, the same add view should appear filled with the added data.
My problem is that i have foreign keys in the table and when i click on edit, the textbox gets filled with foreign key id instead of text stored in that id. And also i have used some jquery in add view for some fields. So while editing those fields aren't displayed at all. Following is the code:

```
public function ride_offer($id = NULL) {

         if (empty($this->data)) {

        $this->data = $this->Rideoffer->read(null, $id);
      // debug($this->data); die;
    }

}
```

`ride_offer` is the add view- i wish to open the same in edit refilled with the added data.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->text('Rideoffer.DropAt', 
                                            array('class' => 'address-text',
                                               ));  ?>
```

just an example- Rideoffer.DropAt shows id instead of actual address stored in Place table . Rideoffer table stores reference of Place as DropAt.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Just to confirm, in the RideOffer table, the DropAt field is the foreign key to another table; and you want to fetch that data and display it in the text box?

Answer (score 0):

You are really making things difficult for yourself by not following the [cakephp naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html). That's how most of the magic happens. You can also use this [inflector](http://inflector.cakephp.org/) lookup to help you with naming.

1. Your action should be `ride_offer.ctp` and your controller action should be `public function rideOffer(){`. Yes, this should still work the way you have it but is not the preferred convention of cake.
2. The naming convention of your form field that is being populated by id's instead of vals should be *_id. I am really not sure how you are getting any kind of `id` inside of your `<?php echo $this->Form->text('Rideoffer.DropAt', 
                                           array('class' => 'address-text',
                                              ));  ?>`
   form field.

if it is a related table. the name should be

```
<?php echo $this->Form->text('drop_at_id', 
                                            array('class' => 'address-text',
                                               ));  ?>
```

and then your controller will magically fill in the vals by passing that model through to the view.

```
//in your controller
$this->set('dropAts', $this->RideOffer->DropAt->find('list'));
```

In response to your comment... your ride_offer table should contain a record called `drop_at_id` **not** `dropAt`

Comment: ok...but the field name is dropAt(which contains id of dropAt Address) so Rideoffer.dropAt means dropAt(i.e. the id) in table Rideoffer

Comment: I understand.. but you won't get what you are looking for unless you use the naming conventions correctly. Your ride_offers table needs to have the field ride_at_id and your ride_at table name has to be ride_ats. If you don't have it this way it will be a nightmare in your model renaming and overriding all of the cake built in functionality.

Comment: Although I agree that you should try to stick with the naming conventions, it's not *impossible* to use your own naming. The only thing that you'll be missing is CakePHP *automatically* finding the right columns to use. So, if this is an existing database and you are not able to modify its schema, you'll have to specify the right columns and tables to use for all relations and models

Comment: @LetterSticker - actually this is my table scenario- place table with place_id as PK. It stores all the places with address, city, etc. Now ride_offer table contains 2 important field for source address n destination address- both of which come from place- so in this case i have 2 place_ids in ride_offer 1 for source n 1 for destination, hence i have named 1 as dropAt n another as pickFrom. How can i have 2 place_id filed names in ride_offer? hope u got my point.